# Close mongodb connection open handles jest express app testing

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm writing tests for my app but I have stumbled on open handles problem.

I have tried all the solutions from google but still, I'm getting this error.
Can you please help me?

I have tried closing all connections but still nothing, I don't know what I can do more.
I'm having the same problem with job schedule

This is my tests

```
import request from 'supertest';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Server } from 'http';
import { app } from '../main';
import connectDB, { disconnect } from '../config/db';

let server: Server;
const globalAny: any = global;
beforeAll((done) => {
  connectDB();
  server = app.listen(4000, () => {
    globalAny.agent = request.agent(server);
    done();
  });
});

afterAll(async () => {
  console.log('closing');
  server.close();
  await mongoose.disconnect();
  mongoose.connection.close();
  await disconnect();

  // @ts-ignore
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 3000)); // avoid jest open handle error
});

it('logins into the app responds with token', (done) => {
  request(server)
    .post('/api/auth')
    .send({ email: 'xxxx@xxx.com', password: 'xxxx$$' })
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(200)
    .end((err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      expect(res.body.success).toBe(true);
      expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('token');
      return done();
    });
});
```

Error I'm getting

```
Jest has detected the following 3 open handles potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  Timeout

      302 |
      303 | // 15:00 hours
    > 304 | schedule.scheduleJob({ hour: 13, minute: 0 }, async () => {
          |          ^
      305 |   await hoursCa(15);
      306 | });
      307 | // 15:30 hours

      at Timeout.Object.<anonymous>.Timeout.start (node_modules/long-timeout/index.js:41:20)
      at new Timeout (node_modules/long-timeout/index.js:22:8)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.setTimeout (node_modules/long-timeout/index.js:5:10)


  ●  TLSWRAP

      17 |     }
      18 |     if (db) {
    > 19 |       await mongoose.connect(db);
         |                      ^
      20 |     }
      21 |     console.log('MongoDB Connected...');
      22 |   } catch (err: any) {

      at Object.resolveSRVRecord (node_modules/mongodb/src/connection_string.ts:78:7)
      at Object.connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/operations/connect.ts:52:12)

  ●  TLSWRAP

      12 | let connection;
      13 | if (db) {
    > 14 |   connection = mongoose.createConnection(db);
         |                         ^
      15 |   autoIncrement.initialize(connection);
      16 | }
      17 | // const AutoIncrement = AutoIncrementFactory(connection);

      at Object.resolveSRVRecord (node_modules/mongodb/src/connection_string.ts:78:7)
      at Object.connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/operations/connect.ts:52:12)
      at node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:417:7
```

Comment: Are you able to solve this?

Comment: Nah still didn't